# Wix dataset collection not getting updated for visiting users but working fine in local environment testing

Tags: collections, frontend, dataset, backend, velo

I have created a collection in Wix,which is working fine when I test it in preview mode but when I publish the site and test it, the dynamic page is showing the data from my preview mode, it is not getting populated with the data from user

I made sure that the permissions such as Read-only, write-only are selected properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you set the permissions properly. It sounds like you are describing the dataset modes and not permissions. There are permissions on the collection. Make sure those are set properly.